# How to change each tab background color on tabPanels in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'll explain the example through the following link.
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html

I want to put a different color on each tab.

ex) plot(background:red), summary(background:orange), table(background:green).

I thought of giving each tab an `tag: class or id` and putting a color in the corresponding `tag: class or id`. But I do not know what to do.

[image]

This is the example what I tried.

```
 mainPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
          .one {background-color: red;}
          ")),
        tags$style(HTML("
          .two {background-color: orange;}
          ")),
        tags$style(HTML("
          .three {background-color: green;}
          ")),
      ),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("plot", class = "one",
                 tags$div(
                   some code..
                 )
        ),

        tabPanel("summary", class = "one",
                 tags$div(
                  some code..
                 ) 
        ), 

        tabPanel("table", class = "one",
                 tags$div(
                  some code..
                 ) 
        )
    )
  )
```

But it's not worked. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It's not worked.
`mainPanel(
      tags$style(HTML("
        .tabs-above > .nav > li > a {
           background-color: #000;
           color: #FFF;
        }")),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Hello", ....)`
Am I using `mainPanel` instead of `fluidPage`?

Comment: If it is not working for you, then make a small example and post the code for that. Figuring out code in a comment is really not very fun.

Comment: I posted again edit using the example.

Comment: I respectfully submit that this is, and was never, a duplicate for two reasons. One: the original link is about setting the color of the active tab, not a background tab. There is a difference since it relies on the active attribute, which obviously the other tabs do not have. Two: the original link solution no longer works as the class hierarchy has changed.

Comment: I have a correct answer too, one that I would like to post.

Comment: library(shiny)
ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a[data-value='summary'] {background-color: orange;}
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a[data-value='plot']    {background-color: red;}
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a[data-value='table']   {background-color: green;}
    .tabbable > .nav > li[class=active]    > a      {background-color: black;}
  ")),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("summary",h2("summary")),
    tabPanel("plot",h2("plot")), 
    tabPanel("table" ,h2("table"))
  )
))
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

Comment: Should I use `fluidPage`? Does `mainPanel` not work?

Comment: Nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok, seeing as I can't get Jaap's attention, I just posted the solution in the  "duplicate" link.