# Set top/bottom margin for tabs in shiny tabsetPanel

Tags: css, r, shiny

Can anyone help with setting the top/bottom margin for the tabs in a tabsetPanel in shiny using CSS?

Here's an example code

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
 ui=shinyUI(
    fixedPage(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Data Input",
                    fixedRow(
                        column(12,
                               h6("test"))
                    )
            )
        )
    )
)
,

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 })
```

)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this. For more info see: [Background color of tabs in shiny tabPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025145/background-color-of-tabs-in-shiny-tabpanel/43201952#43201952)

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
ui=shinyUI(
fixedPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data Input",
             tags$style(HTML("
              .tabbable > .nav > li > a {margin-top:50px;}")),
             fixedRow(
               column(12,
                      h6("test"))
             )
    )
  )
)
)
,

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @timfaber, that works. I personally prefer tags$head(tags$style( HTML(' .nav {margin-top:30px;}')))