# Highlight link when active in shiny r

Tags: r, list, shiny, highlight

I have this code for listing links:

```
nav_links <- tags$ul(
  tags$li(
    tags$a(href = paste0(baseurl,"/"), "home"), 
  ),
  tags$li(
    tags$a(href = paste0(baseurl,"/page2"), "page2"), 
  ),
  tags$li(
    tags$a(href = paste0(baseurl,"/page3"), "page3"), 
  )
)
```

Then

```
page_3 <- function(){
  page(
    href = '/page3',
    ui = fluidPage(titlePanel("Viewing data"),
                   nav_links,
                   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("virus",
                                 label = "Select virus",
                                 choices = viruses,
                                 selected = ""),
                   ),
                   mainPanel(dataTableOutput("dt")))),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      data <- eventReactive(input$virus, {
        infile <- 'data/vulture/sample_all_virus_load.tsv'
        tab <- read.table(infile,header=T,sep='\t', quote="")
        df <- data.frame(tab)
        if (input$virus != '') {
          df <- df[df$virus==input$virus,]
        }
        df
      })
      
      output$dt <- renderDataTable({
        req(data())
        print(data)
        datatable(
          data()
        )})
    }
  )
}
```

nav_links is displayed in all pages. How do I highlight the link in nav_links when it is active? Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried this [Highlight active tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508943/highlight-active-tabs) but it didn't highlight anything. I also tried this [Background color of the active tab in Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73731970/background-color-of-the-active-tab-in-shiny-app) and it didn't work either.